# Dual boot two windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, multi-boot

I want to have two windows 7, One for daily use and another for doing experimental stuff on it so I can have a good working windows 7 always.

Let's name them A and B. I want to be able to boot into A and also able to boot into B from boot loader menu, and then when I'm in A I want to be able to run B in a VM and vice versa.

I just want both of them to be able to act as a host and guest os.
What should I do ?

Comment: I had a little different situation at one point.  I had a MacPro with a 7 install on a separate HDD that I could boot into via bootcamp.  Also used that same HDD as the image for a Parallels VM.  While it technically "worked", Windows really didn't like it.  Always required a logout when returning to one after booting from the other.  YMMV of course with different hardware and virtualization software.  Just sayin :)

Answer (score 0):

I know for sure that you can use physical disks (or partitions) and use it in `VMWare Workstation`: [here the link](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_disk_add_raw.html) to the documentation.
So what you can do is to create your dual boot normally and then install `VMWare Workstation` (note: I don't know if others free products support physical driver but I think yes. Check `Virtual Box` documentation) on each partitions (or each disks).

You should be VERY careful because it's a very dangerous operation